# Custom query for RA Create and Edit components

Tags: react-admin

We use RA with "ra-data-graphql-simple" data provider.
Our backend was designed to work with RA CRUD format, and this data-provider fit most of our use cases until now.

Now, we need other behavior for one of our resources.
Instead of "updateResource" mutation, we need to use "screenResource" mutation.
Instead of "createResource" - "initiateResource".
Body of this mutations stays the same as with "update" and "create", only mutation names changing.
This requirement related to backend architecture.

Other resources will continue to use default "update" and "create" mutations.

So, I probably can expand "ra-data-graphql-simple", and add new methods to it - "screen" and "initiate".

But a question is, how can I continue to use Edit and Create RA components in this case? Because, even if I add new methods to data-provider, these components will continue to call "useCreate" and "useUpdate", instead of my new methods, and I don't see how to alter this behavior.

Maybe I need to modify "ra-data-graphql-simple" original "create" and "update" methods, instead of adding new methods. But I'm not sure it's possible. I tried this aproach to modify it:

```
const customBuildQuery = (introspectionResults: any) => {
const buildDefaultQuery = buildQuery(introspectionResults);

return (type: string, resource: string, params: any) => {
    if (resource === 'YourResourceName') {
        // Customize the query for the specific resource
        return {
            // Your custom query here
        };
    }

    // Use the default query for other resources
    return buildDefaultQuery(type, resource, params);
};
```

But seems this approach don't work.

Comment: Have you had a look at ra-data-graphql-simple's [Overriding a specific query](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/packages/ra-data-graphql-simple#overriding-a-specific-query) documentation? Alternatively, react-admin's [Lifecycle Callbacks](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/withLifecycleCallbacks.html) may help.